# Is it possible to locate a write/printf call in IDA

Tags: reverse-engineering

total noob here, hope this is OK

I'm using IDA trying to reverse engineer a little program I have. Currently the only thing I know about it is that it prints a string when started. I tried looking in the string section for that string but couldn't find it (guessing the string was generated mid-run).

So, I figured that if I could find a call to a function that prints data, I would be able to lock-on that part in the program. Is that possible? and if so, how?

If not, what should I do in order to find what happens after that string is printed? (the program awaits input, and upon bad input, exits...)

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try to search some classical windows API such as "printf" in IDA, i.e. you can search by key word "printf"

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ltrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html), it intercepts calls to dynamically linked libraries.